# Google GData - how to send a right Google username?

Tags: c#, gdata

I'm trying to send a video to YouTube using Google.GData on C#. The problem is that I can't understand what kind of a username should a send to Google.

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("applicationName", "developerKey", "userName", "passWord");
```

As you can see, I need to send 4 parameters to Google and one of them is video uploader's username. I tried to send my Gmail adress (without @gmail.com), but it didn't work - I've received Incorrect Credentials exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable less secure apps here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

However, using v3 of the YouTube API would be a better option. For code examples see here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. It looks like that information can be helpful for me.